# redirect the homepage using .htaccess outside of WordPress

Tags: htaccess

For a marketing reason, my client needs a standalone HTML Page as the "temporary homepage"

What I would like to do is redirect the homepage to a page OUTSIDE of the WordPress ecosystem - I guess this is done using HTACCESS rules...

Can I even do this without breaking WordPress?

Thanks

Comment: If you just add index.html to the root of your WordPress installation that should become the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

As @JacobPeattie suggested in comments:

> If you just add `index.html` to the root of your WordPress installation that should become the homepage.

This does, however, require that the `DirectoryIndex` is set appropriately. For example:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

The `DirectoryIndex` is the document that Apache tries to serve when you request a directory. In this case, the document root. Specifying a relative URL-path will look for that file relative to the directory being requested.

Or, to have multiple directory index documents (that are tried in turn):

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

(`index.php` would ordinarily be required for WordPress.)

You can change `index.html` to anything you like.

You can also specify a file in a specific location elsewhere on the filesystem (providing it is publicly accessible). For example:

```
DirectoryIndex /path/to/alternative/homepage.php
```

But this will mean that if you request `/path/to/any-directory/` then it will also serve `/path/to/alternative/homepage.php` (via an internal subrequest).

The default WordPress front-controller (directives in `.htaccess`) don't do anything when you request the homepage (or any directory for that matter). It relies on mod_dir (ie. `DirectoryIndex`) to make the internal subrequest for `index.php`. Only when you request `/<something>` might the request be manually rewritten to `index.php`.

---

Alternately, you can use mod_rewrite, *before* the WordPress front-controller to internally rewrite the request for the homepage (`/`) to your alternative homepage.

For example:

```
# Internal rewrite to alternative homepage
RewriteRule ^$ /path/to/alternative/homepage.php [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
# : (WordPress front-controller goes here)
```

---

If you did literally want to "redirect" to a temporary homepage then you just need to add the `R` flag to the above directive. (Although the internal rewrite/subrequest, as mention above, would be preferable in most scenarios.)

For example:

```
# External "redirect" to alternative homepage
RewriteRule ^$ /path/to/alternative/homepage.php [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
# : (WordPress front-controller goes here)
```

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect.

Comment: For me, option with [R,L] solved my needs.  

     `RewriteRule ^$ https://www.mywpwebsite.com/institutional [R,L]`  

Thus, only the home page is redirected, all other pages remain unchanged.  
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect the one page to another page then it is possible with the `.htaccess` file, add the below rule in the `.htaccess`:

```
Redirect 301 https://example1.com/ https://example2.com/
```

Don't forget to change the example URLs.

Comment: The mod_alias `Redirect` directive matches against a root-relative (starting with a slash) URL - not an absolute URL - so the above directive will fail to do anything. However, the `Redirect` directive is also _prefix-matching_, so this would redirect _everything_, not just the homepage! (But I don't believe the OP mentioned anything about redirecting to another domain?)